# check duplicate records for particular row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to check there is any duplicate record for that row.
means as per table structure

> if( C1_CADNO=C2_CADNO or C1_CADNO=C3_CADNO or C2_CADNO=C3_CADNO )
>   then
>   display that record

And my Table having 10 columns like C1_CADNO.....C10_CADNO

[My Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9T8M.png)

Comment: So, you have 10 columns and want to get the rows where any two of them contain the same entry?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer i have to compare 10 columns to each others and Find same entry between columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.* FROM TableName t
WHERE ( C1_CADNO = C2_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C3_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C3_CADNO )
```

> but my table having 10 columns like
>   C1_CADNO,C2_CADNO,C3_CADNO.....C10_CADNO –

Then this SQL is made for you:

```
SELECT t.* FROM TableName t
WHERE ( t.C1_CADNO = t.C2_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C3_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C4_CADNO
     OR C1_CADNO = C5_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C6_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C7_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C8_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C9_CADNO 
     OR C1_CADNO = C10_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C3_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C4_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C5_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C6_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C7_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C8_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C9_CADNO 
     OR C2_CADNO = C10_CADNO 
     OR C3_CADNO = C4_CADNO 
     OR C3_CADNO = C5_CADNO
     OR C3_CADNO = C6_CADNO
     OR C3_CADNO = C7_CADNO
     OR C3_CADNO = C8_CADNO
     OR C3_CADNO = C9_CADNO
     OR C3_CADNO = C10_CADNO
     OR C4_CADNO = C5_CADNO 
     OR C4_CADNO = C6_CADNO
     OR C4_CADNO = C7_CADNO
     OR C4_CADNO = C8_CADNO
     OR C4_CADNO = C9_CADNO
     OR C4_CADNO = C10_CADNO
     OR C5_CADNO = C6_CADNO
     OR C5_CADNO = C7_CADNO
     OR C5_CADNO = C8_CADNO
     OR C5_CADNO = C9_CADNO
     OR C5_CADNO = C10_CADNO
     OR C6_CADNO = C7_CADNO
     OR C6_CADNO = C8_CADNO
     OR C6_CADNO = C9_CADNO
     OR C6_CADNO = C10_CADNO
     OR C7_CADNO = C8_CADNO
     OR C8_CADNO = C9_CADNO
     OR C8_CADNO = C10_CADNO
     OR C9_CADNO = C10_CADNO
)
```

Now you know why it's important to [normalize](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191178%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) tables ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE 

   C1_CADNO IN (C2_CADNO,C3_CADNO,C4_CADNO,...C10_CADNO)
   OR 
   C2_CADNO IN (C3_CADNO,C4_CADNO,...C10_CADNO)
   OR 
   C3_CADNO IN (C4_CADNO,...C10_CADNO)
   OR 
   C4_CADNO IN (C5_CADNO,...C10_CADNO)
   ...
   OR 
   C8_CADNO IN (C9_CADNO,...C10_CADNO)
   OR 
   C9_CADNO = C10_CADNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enumerating all the permutations, just count the distinct values in the row.  If the count is too small, then you must have duplicates.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value)
  FROM (VALUES (C1_CADNO),(C2_CADNO),(C3_CADNO),(C4_CADNO),(C5_CADNO),(C6_CADNO),(C7_CADNO),(C8_CADNO),(C9_CADNO),(C10_CADNO) ) t(value)
) < 10
```

Comment: I was contemplating a similar approach. Instead of `WHERE (SELECT COUNT(...) ...) < 10` I was thinking of something along the lines of `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES ...) HAVING COUNT(*) <> COUNT(DISTINCT ...))`, the idea being that if the number of columns changed, you would only need to modify the VALUES list. In your case you would need to remember to change the `10` as well, although as a whole your query is definitely simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

will this work,

```
select CADNO,count(*) cnt from 
(select C1_CADNO [CADNO] from table1
union all
select C2_CADNO from table1
......
....
select C10_CADNO from table1
)t4 group by CADNO
having count(*)>1
```